# Is there a reason to place operator ""s into std::literals::string_literals?

Tags: c++, c++14, string-literals, user-defined-literals

I'm pretty surprised to discover that this code doesn't compile (assuming we're using a C++14 compiler):

```
std::cout << "hello world!\n"s;
```

The error showed by ideone is the [following](http://ideone.com/NiTBaL):

> unable to find string literal operator 'operator""s'

Luckily is pretty simple to fix with a `using` statement:

```
using namespace std::literals::string_literals;
std::cout << "hello world!\n"s; // Compiles!
```

I'm wondering if there's a reason behind the placement of the standard string user defined literals in a different namespace than the `std::string` itself; I have been thinking on it and I cannot figure the reason.

Isn't possible to collide with the `operator""s` from `std::chrono` because they operate with different types:

```
auto ten_seconds = 10s; // ten seconds
auto some_string = "some string"s; // some string
```

I was thinking that the resason could be to not collide with my user defined literals but *the standard says* that [I must preceed them with `'_'` underscore](http://ideone.com/AOUoqI):

> warning: literal operator suffixes not preceded by '_' are reserved for future standardization

So, I'm pretty surprised, anyone knows the reason behind placing the string literal operator into the `std::literals::string_literals`?

Thanks.

Comment: I much prefer doing `using namespace std::literals;` to doing `using std::operator"" s;` or `using namespace std;`

Comment: Better yet, just watch [CppCon 2014: Stephan Lavavej "STL Features And Implementation Techniques"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dTeKf5Oek2c), he briefly talks about UDL's in inline namespaces.